# Eclipse PHP Oxygen (Eclipse 2017) How to sort members?

Tags: php, eclipse, sorting

Does Eclipse Oxygen PHP (2017) support sorting members in a class or just members in a file? In Java I'm accustomed to source->sort members, but I can understand that is difficult in a loosely typed language like PHP. If the answer is just 'no it's unsupported' I'll accept it.

For example, I want to sort this before I check into a source control so that it is easy to identify changes by team members with a simple diff:

```
<?php
class myClass{
    private $myVar1;
    private $myVar2;

    public function getMyVar1(){
        return $this->myVar1;
    }

    public function __construct(string $myStr){
        $this->myVar1 = $myStr;
    }           

    public function setMyVar2($myVar2){
        $this->myVar2 = $myVar2;  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not the answer you are looking for but an answer nonetheless, it seems as though it is not possible to do so in Eclipse Oxygen as the option is missing from the preferences as can be seen in the image below:

[image: No option.]

**Update #1**

I've searched through the Eclipse Marketplace and have not been able to find a plugin which allows you to sort members for PHP.

### Update #2

I've created an *Enhancement* request Eclipse's official tracker, find the thread [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521545) so please vote on it to get it up the todo list.

Comment: I saw the same when looking through the preferences and documentation. I was hoping someone knew of a magic trick or super secret plug-in. I'll leave the question open for a bit more fishing, but likely I'll just accept your answer. Thank you for investigating!

Comment: @PhilipAttisano yep, I've checked the marketplace too but no such luck.

Comment: I see the Enhancement Request and will upvote. Thank you for being extremely helpful!